# 403 error while using angular-azure-blob-service

Tags: angular, azure, cors, blob

I have done all the steps mentioned in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-azure-blob-service).

But this still gives the error :

> The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://wtiotsstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/wdiotscontainer/Capture.JPG?sv=2017-11-09&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-07-19T19:26:21Z&st=2018-07-19T11:26:21Z&spr=https,http&sig=%2FM1%2BRpDOZiHduYdtf9%2FpnrVTn97fV2ixglKh5bfjz6Y%3D%20&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 403 error while using angular-azure-blob-service

If you want to send a cross-origin request successfully, the request must match the CORS configuration including the request origin, headers & response headers. For more information please refer to [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Support for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-cors-requests).

You could add the CORS setting for **storage blob** service. By default, CORS is disabled for each service

[image]

> You can also use the wildcard character '*' to allow all origin domains to make requests via CORS.